# Python cProfile module throws exception in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to profile the execution of a function within my Lambda handler:

```
import cProfile
import time

def myfunc(reps, sleeptime):
    for x in range(reps):
        print(f"rep {x}")
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
        
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    x = 3
    y = 0.25
    cProfile.run('myfunc(x, y)', sort="cumtime")
```

However, when I run this Lambda, I get the following output:

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'myfunc' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    cProfile.run('myfunc(x, y)', sort="cumtime")
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/cProfile.py", line 17, in run
    return _pyprofile._Utils(Profile).run(statement, filename, sort)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/profile.py", line 54, in run
    prof.run(statement)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/cProfile.py", line 96, in run
    return self.runctx(cmd, dict, dict)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/cProfile.py", line 101, in runctx
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two work-arounds:

First, use `cProfile.runctx()`, explicitly passing the current globals and locals:

```
cProfile.runctx('myfunc(x, y)', globals(), locals(), sort="cumtime")
```

Second, create a profiler instance and explicitly enable/disable for the function call:

```
import cProfile
import pstats
import time

# ...
        
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    x = 3
    y = 0.25
    profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    profiler.enable()
    myfunc(x, y)
    profiler.disable()
    stats = pstats.Stats(profiler).sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CUMULATIVE)
    stats.print_stats()
```

I have no idea why the `profile()` function doesn't properly gather globals and locals. I assume that AWS has modified the `cProfile` module for its own purposes.